# How do I create View/Filter to allow Teachers to see all Student assignments in a library, but the students to only be able to see their own?

Tags: list-view, filter, custom

So I use SharePoint in school for students turn in assignments and for teachers to grade them via Office 365.

I have a SharePoint user group (Teachers) who need to see all the documents uploaded to the library by all the students. However, each student should only see the documents they added to the library and nobody else's.

Can a specific view be assigned to each user group based on their user ID? I.e. Teachers Group are directed the "All Documents" view and Students Group is filtered by [Me]. Can I prevent students accessing the "All Documents" view?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Audience Targeting on the List View Web Parts.  For instance for the default LVWP for your document library, set its target audience to be the Teachers group.  Then add another LVWP for the same document library to the same page, set its target audience to be the Students group, set up a view for that LVWP that filters by Created by = [Me], and show no toolbar so they can't change the view. They should still be able to upload documents through the Ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about preventing access to a view, but you could prevent access to the documents.

I've had this requirement before, so I create a SharePoint 2010 list workflow with an impersonation step that, when the document is created/uploaded, permissions are replaced with the user who created it, and whoever else needs access.  I try to use groups as much as possible with the "whoever else needs access", as that will make management a little easier.

With this you can also make it so the student can't change the document once they upload it by making their permissions Read.

I have found that with SharePoint Online, finding where the permissions are broken is much easier, so I don't worry too much about this, though I try to document where I have done this.

[image: Screenshot of workflow]